# How to determine the size of array from txt file

Tags: java, arrays

This is a part of my code and I want to know how to determine the size of array from a txt file

```
while (scanner.hasNextDouble())
{
   Double[] con = new Double[15]; //makes array
   for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
   {
      a[i] = scanner.nextDouble(); // data is saved in array
   }
}
```

Comment: can you post a sample file content?

Comment: Does it have to be an array?  I would suggest using some kind of list, maybe an ArrayList.  Then you don't have to think about the size of the array.

Comment: it has to be an array

Comment: But why it has to be an array? You can "convert" list to array later - when needed...

Comment: Why not use a Vector? Or you have to scan the whole file to get a size, or you can use a dynamic array/vector.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you can define a new variable named `int sum =0;` and underneath `while(scanner.hasNextDouble()){` you can add `sum++;` to count the length of the array and make your `Double [] con= new Double [sum];`

Comment: You meant to read the file first and create array later, or what?

Comment: `FileInputStream w = new FileInputStream(args[0]);//reads a file` <br/>
           ` Scanner scanner  = new Scanner(w);`<br/>
`int sum = 0;`<br/>
           ` while(scanner.hasNextDouble())`<br/>
            {
sum++;
              Double [] con= new Double [sum];//makes array
              for (int i=0;i<con.length; i++)
             ` {`<br/>
               ` con[i]=scanner.nextDouble();//data is saved in array`<br/>
           `   }`

Comment: The code you've posted makes no sense. On the first iteration `sum` get's one. Then you're creating an array witht the size one, read one value and do what with it? But anyway, on the next iteration you just checked, that there is _one_ next double, but you're creating `con` a second time (this also deletes the previously read data), with size 2 and read two times, which might fail, since you can't be sure, that there are 2 values available. The next iteration creates another `con` array, and now you're trying to read three consecutive values, which also might fail.

Comment: So at the end ... you neither have an array with all the values of the file and you also don't have the correct array size (except you store it somewhere else) and this code is also very error-prone.

Answer (score 2):

If you are only after the size (length), then you can use a list. For example:

```
  FileInputStream w = new FileInputStream(args[0]); // Opens a file
  Scanner scanner  = new Scanner(w);
  List<Double> numbers = new ArrayList<Double>();
  while (scanner.hasNextDouble()) // Reads double values from the file
  {
      numbers.add(scanner.nextDouble());
  }
  int length = numbers.size(); // The requested size
  Double[] con = numbers.toArray(new Double[length]); // Answer as array
```

Comment: it must be array not arraylist

Comment: @AchilleasEftychiou you can convert list to array, but you cannot use array if you do not know the number of items (numbers) in file...

Comment: Exactly. I have added the conversion of the array to a list.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add elements to `List` and convert the `List` to an `array` and calculate the length like this:

```
List<Double> con = new ArrayList<Double>();
while (scanner.hasNextDouble())
{           
    con.add(scanner.nextDouble());
}
Double[] doubArray = con.toArray(new Double[con.size()]);
int sizeOfArray = doubArray.length;
```

Comment: Do you mean `new ArrayList<Double>();` for every `hasNextDouble()`?

Comment: Ok, looks much better now :)